# Linq query using select box to display data

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to implement a linq query that allows the user to select for example, 1-10 displayed in a 
select box and it displays the corresponding 'CarID' depending on which one the user clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to the below working example:

1.Model

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarID { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public string EngineSize { get; set; }

}
```

2.PageModel:

```
 public class Query1Model : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorPageDbContext _context;

    public Query1Model(RazorPageDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Car> CarID { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Options { get; set; }
    [BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
    public int SearchCarID { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        Options = _context.Cars.Select(a =>
                             new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Value = a.CarID.ToString(),
                                 Text = a.CarID.ToString()
                             }).ToList();

        if (SearchCarID != 0)
        {
            var CarQuery = (from s in _context.Cars
                            where s.CarID == SearchCarID
                            select s);
            CarID = await CarQuery.ToListAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            CarID = await _context.Cars.ToListAsync();
        }
        return Page();
    }
 }
```

3.Razor Page:

```
<h2>Filter By CarID</h2>

<form>
<p>
    Select the CarID you wish to display:
    <select asp-for="SearchCarID" asp-items="@Model.Options">
        <option value="">Pick one</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</p>
</form>

<h3> Here is the CarIDs you requested</h3>
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarID[0].CarID)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarID[0].Model)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarID[0].Manufacturer)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarID[0].EngineSize)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.CarID)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.CarID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Model)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.Manufacturer)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => item.EngineSize)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
</table>
```

4.Result:
[image]

Comment: Thankyou very much xueli, this is exactly what I was looking for! Very grateful merry christmas!

Comment: Would you know how to only display what index of the drop down list is selected instead of having them all display when the list is null?

Comment: Not clear about your meaning. What is the list in “ when the list is null ” ?

Comment: sorry i did not explain that well, when i open the query page it displays all the carIDs and corresponding data, i would like it to only display the data when the user selects which id they wish to see from the down down list. Again i really appreciate your help thankyou!

Comment: Xueli is there anyway you could explain how to implement the same query but only let the user select to display minimum or maximum engine size using the select box? if it helps i can ask it in another question and you could reply to that one for reputation?